# Refresh Internet Explorer on detection of Error 500

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, error-handling

I have code that looks at an already opened Internet Explorer browser, copies the data to a clipboard, and then pastes it into a worksheet. The web page itself is coded to refresh every 90 seconds.  My Excel VBA code runs on a timer and the Workbook is constantly updating itself with the new data from the web.

The program runs great, until the website has a random server hiccup and throws a **`500 Internal Server Error`**, and because of this:

1. I'm no longer able to copy to the clipboard,
2. The web page stops refreshing.  Essentially it leaves my Excel program dead in the water until someone manually gets on and refreshes the web page.

I need some code to recognize when the web page fails to load and to automatically refresh IE when this happens.

Here is my current code:

```
'**** FIND OPEN IE WINDOW THAT HAS MY DESIRED URL LOADED ****
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ie_count = objShell.Windows.Count

For x = 0 To (ie_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).document.Title

    If my_url Like "http://myurl.com" & "*" Then 
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
    End If
Next x


'**** COPY TABLE FROM WEB, PASTE IN SHEET ****

Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim tables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable
Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject

With ie
    .Visible = False
    While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set doc = .document
    Set tables = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
    Set table = tables(0)
    Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
    clipboard.SetText table.outerHTML
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    clipboard.PutInClipboard
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    sh3.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

Comment: Which line of code does it stop on when IE throws the error error?

Answer (score 0):

If it's stopping execution on a specific line of code every time, put this just before that line:

```
On Error Resume Next
TryAgain:
```

...and this just after that line:

```
On Error GoTo 0
If Err Then
   Debug.Print "Error #" & Err & ": " & Err.Description
   ie.Refresh
   Do: DoEvents: Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4
   Err.Clear
   GoTo TryAgain
End If
```

Comment: `If Err Then` block will never run, since `On Error ..` statement resets `Err` state, like `Err.Clear` does.